# Why does elasticsearch fail to return a result in this specific scenario

Tags: elasticsearch

I am banging my head against the desk trying to figure this out.  When searching the field customer.FirstName on a record where the first name is "Willa" I get results back for "W", "WI", "WIL", "WILLA", but NOT **"WILL"**.  For example, the following works:

```
curl -XPOST "http://.../someindex/_search?pretty=true" -d'
{
   "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "will",
     "fields": [
        "FirstName"
     ]
    }
   },
   "script_fields": {
   "terms": {
     "script": "doc[field].values",
     "params": {
        "field": "customer.FirstName"
     }
   }
  }
}'
```

and the result of the above is:

```
{
"took": 0,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
  "total": 2,
  "successful": 2,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 1.8629173,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "someindex",
        "_type": "customer",
        "_id": "585B1F34-5822-4859-802D-E2218D1E6FCF",
        "_score": 1.8629173,
        "fields": {
           "terms": [
              "w",
              "wi",
              "wil",
              "will",
              "willa"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
 }
}
```

However, the following doesn't return any results:

```
curl -XPOST "http://.../someindex/_search?pretty=true" -d'
{
   "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "willa",
     "fields": [
        "FirstName"
     ]
    }
   },
   "script_fields": {
   "terms": {
     "script": "doc[field].values",
     "params": {
        "field": "customer.FirstName"
     }
   }
  }
}'
```

This is how customer.FirstName Willa is indexed:

```
GET /devpac2/_analyze?field=customer.FirstName&text=Willa

{
"tokens": [
  {
     "token": "w",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 1,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 1
  },
  {
     "token": "wi",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 2,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 2
  },
  {
     "token": "wil",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 3,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 3
  },
  {
     "token": "will",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 4,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 4
  },
  {
     "token": "willa",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 5,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 5
  }
]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is "Will" on the stop words list?

Comment: I think you are right!  According to this post http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Search-Stop-word-td2690386.html#a2690542 "will" is a stop word